# PHP login user to a different domain and redirect

Tags: php

I'm looking at a smart way of logging a user from an external service (different domain) into a website and then making them redirect to that website with them already logged in.

Would it be possible to accomplish that using PHP or any web technology?

As an example, let's say there's a website with a domain name of example.com. That website contains a login page with a URL of example.com/login. Furthermore, let's assume this website is not managed by us. In other words, we don't have access to its APIs.

Let's also say there's a portal with a domain name of portal.com. This portal is completely irrelevant to the website example.com. Also, this portal is completely managed by us and therefore we can write PHP scripts directly on it.

Would it be possible to log in a user from portal.com into example.com?

My first instinct was to use web scraping by going to example.com/login, logging in the user and then redirecting them from portal.com to example.com with them already logged in. However, I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: This question is quite vague. You need to be far more specific about the nature of the service, and the type of login of the target website.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Fair enough. I've edited my original question with more detail. Could you please review it?

Comment: I have reviewed it. It is a lot clearer now, and I can see why you wanted to use scraping. Clearly that won't work. This kind of logging in can be useful, but it can also easily be used for nefarious purposes, kike the automated testing of an illegally obtained list of usernames and passwords. Given this fact I cannot help you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for your response. Could you at least re-open the question so that others can advise?

Comment: _"Would it be possible to log in a user from portal.com into example.com?"_ - if example.com just needed "standard" credentials like username + password POSTed from anywhere, and without any other restrictions (such as form security tokens), then you could simply submit a form with the correct action and fields, from _your_ site. But most likely it won't be that simple, because most sites these days have measures in place against this.

Comment: _"My first instinct was to use web scraping by going to example.com/login, logging in the user and then redirecting them from portal.com to example.com with them already logged in."_ - then that login would happen "on" your server, instead of the user's client browser - so that doesn't help you much. You would be "logging in" your server to that other site, and not my browser.

Comment: Unless example.com is willing to actively participate in this (and provide necessary APIs, widgets or whatever) from their end, IMHO this should not be _attempted_ in the first place. Let users handle this via their own, client-side password manager then, instead of trying to insert yourself into this as a middleman.

Comment: I did vote to reopen your question when I commented. Depending on the reputation of the voter it might require multiple votes to reopen a question. In my case it is usually 3 voters. Anyway, I see your question has been opened now.